# SQL Where condition with multiple condition

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query like below: My requirement is If Development env is DEV, then condition in where clause should be Date<Getdate-500 otherwise condition should be Date<Getdate-100. all other conditions will be same in both cases. How can we do this. Thanks

```
INSERT INTO @TableA (ID) 
    SELECT DISTINCT(ID)
    FROM EMP
    WHERE (Act_flag = 1 AND Date < GETDATE() - 100) OR Act_flag = 0
```

Comment: Please add DBMS tag or tool tag. You can get the system name using some clause and use it like this. `Where case when SERVER_HOST='PROD.xx.com' AND ((Act_flag=1 AND Date<Getdate-100) OR Act_flag=0) then 1 WHEN ERVER_HOST='DEV.xx.com' AND ((Act_flag=1 AND Date<Getdate-500) OR Act_flag=0) then 1 ELSE 0 end =1  `

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO @TableA (ID) 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM EMP
    WHERE 
((Env != 'DEV') AND ((Act_flag = 0) OR (Act_flag = 1 AND Date < GETDATE() - 100))) 
OR 
((Env = 'DEV') AND ((Act_flag = 0) OR (Act_flag = 1 AND Date < GETDATE() - 500)))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Prakhar.
But It seems where conditions are wrongly placed with AND and OR. Isn't it?

Comment: No Preeti, I've added parenthesis for the separation. Can you please specify which condition is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may create a separate table, say ENVIRONMENT table, to store what environment it is.

In DEV, the table would appear like this -

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| EnvName | DEV |

In PROD, the table would appear like this -

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| EnvName | PROD |

Then, you may read this table and store the value of key 'EnvName' in a local variable, say envName, and use it something like below -

```
INSERT INTO @TableA (ID) 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM EMP
    WHERE 
((EnvName = 'DEV' AND ((Act_flag = 1 AND Date < GETDATE() - 500) OR Act_flag = 0)) OR 
(EnvName <> 'DEV' AND ((Act_flag = 1 AND Date < GETDATE() - 100) OR Act_flag = 0)))
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks Rajiv,
Can we do it using CASE statment with all the above condition.

WHERE (Act_flag = 1 AND Date < GETDATE() - 100) OR Act_flag = 0

Comment: CASE evaluates to an expression and is not required here, unless you want to over-complicate your code. Please accept this as an answer if it solved your original query.

Comment: Rajeev what about the other conditions in Where clause? Can you please include those also. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Preeti, would you care to explain why have you unaccepted the answer? The other accepted answer (which was posted after mine) doesn't even explain what 'Env' stands for.